# How to connect to custom network when building image/container in Docker-Java API

Tags: java, docker, containers, ethereum, geth

I am using the Docker-Java API found here https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java.

I have a dockerfile that I have to build 3 containers for. I am trying to automate the process of building 3 images and the commands to go with them when running the shell inside. The 3 containers must be in the same local network in order for them to communicate. I am able to do this manually just fine...

So first, using the docker-java API, I am building a custom network using the following function:

```java
private void createNetwork() {
    CreateNetworkResponse networkResponse = dockerClient.createNetworkCmd()
        .withName("ETH")
        .withDriver("bridge")
        .withAttachable(true)
        .exec();
    System.out.printf("Network %s created...\n", networkResponse.getId());
}
```

This works great, and if I run `docker network ls`, I can see the ETH network listed.

The next step is building the image. I am running the following function:

```java
public String buildImage(String tag) {
    String imageID = dockerClient.buildImageCmd()
        .withDockerfile(new File("/Dockerfile"))
        .withPull(true)
        .withNoCache(false)
        .withTags(new HashSet<>(Collections.singletonList(tag)))
        .withNetworkMode("ETH")
        .exec(new BuildImageResultCallback())
        .awaitImageId();
    System.out.println("Built image: " + imageID);
    return imageID;
}
```

So the image builds fine and I can see the image when I run the `docker images` command in terminal. I do expect that the image to be connected to the `ETH` network, but I do not see that.

I thought that maybe I have to connect to the network when creating the container instead then, so I pass the same commands I would if I were to manually do this when building the container through the following function:

```
private String createContainer(String name, String imageID, int port) {
        CreateContainerResponse container = dockerClient
                .createContainerCmd(name)
                .withImage(imageID)
                .withCmd("docker", "run", "--rm", "-i", "-p", port + ":" + port, "--net=ETH", name)
                .withExposedPorts(new ExposedPort(port))
                .exec();
        dockerClient.startContainerCmd(container.getId()).exec();
        return container.getId();
}
```

Unfortunately, when passing in the arguments like this, the built container does not show up in the `ETH` network when running the command `docker network inspect ETH`.

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. If I build the image using the API, and then run the following command manually, `docker run --rm -it -p 8545:8545 --net=ETH miner_one` everything works fine. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Images aren't connected to networks.  (What's the IP address of a jar file?)  You almost certainly need to include it in your call to create the container; you would not specify `docker run` options there (or a `docker run` command even) but instead specify the same options using the Docker API.

Comment: Ahh @DavidMaze thank you. That's helpful. In that case, I need to be attaching to the ETH network in the createContainer function by specifying the ETH network there.. but I don't see any method call to set the network when calling ```.createContainer()```.

Answer (score 2):

The docker-java client supports a subset of the Docker Remote API. To connect to a network when you create the container set the `NetworkMode` field 
(see *HostConfig -> NetworkMode* in [Container Create section](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.37/#operation/ContainerCreate))

> Network mode to use for this container. Supported standard values are:
>   bridge, host, none, and container:.  Any other value is taken
>   as a custom network's name to which this container should connect to.

Therefore, in order for the container to connect to the custom network set the value of the network mode to `ETH`.

In Java, for older versions of the Docker-Java client, use the `withNetworkMode()` method:

```
CreateContainerResponse container = dockerClient
                .createContainerCmd(name)
                .withImage(imageID)
                .withNetworkMode("ETH")
                ...
```

In the latest version, the methods in `CreateContainerCmd` used to set the fields in `HostConfig` are deprecated. Use `withHostConfig()` instead:

```
 CreateContainerResponse container = dockerClient.createContainerCmd(name)
     .withImage(imageID)
     .withHostConfig(HostConfig.newHostConfig().withNetworkMode("ETH"))
     ...
```

Here is a basic example:

```
List<Network> networks = dockerClient.listNetworksCmd().withNameFilter("ETH").exec();
    if (networks.isEmpty()) {
      CreateNetworkResponse networkResponse = dockerClient
          .createNetworkCmd()
          .withName("ETH")
          .withAttachable(true)
          .withDriver("bridge").exec();
      System.out.printf("Network %s created...\n", networkResponse.getId());
    }

    CreateContainerResponse container = dockerClient
        .createContainerCmd("ubuntu")
        .withName("my-ubuntu")
        .withCmd("sleep", "10")
        .withHostConfig(HostConfig
            .newHostConfig()
            .withNetworkMode("ETH")
            .withAutoRemove(true))
        .exec();

    String containerId = container.getId();
    dockerClient.startContainerCmd(containerId).exec();

    Network ethNetwork = dockerClient.inspectNetworkCmd()
        .withNetworkId("ETH")
        .exec();

    Set<String> containerIds = ethNetwork.getContainers().keySet();
    if(containerIds.contains(containerId)) {
      System.out.printf("Container with id:%s is connected to network %s%n", containerId, ethNetwork.getName());
    }
```

It creates a network named `ETH` and a container `my-ubuntu` from an `ubuntu` image. The container is connected to the `ETH` network.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried adding the code ``` .withHostConfig(HostConfig.newHostConfig().withNetworkMode("ETH"))```, but I still don't see the container when running ```docker network inspect ETH```.

Comment: @SameetAhmed Is the container running when you inspect the `ETH` network? When the container exits it is removed from the containers list in the network. I have updated my answer adding a working example.